# HTML/jQuery Show and Hide table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that is working as a contact form which its contents will be changed depending on a dropdown menu.

This is my table:

```
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Contact Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Representative Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Representative Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Representative Mobile Number:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Contact Type:
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="contactSelect" id="contactSelect" onchange="changeVal();"> <!-- Function showHide Show work on table elements -->
                    <option value="default" selected>Pelease select ...</option> <!-- Hide all 4 rows below -->
                    <option value="General" id="cat2">General Inquiry</option> <!-- Shows Option 1 Row -->
                    <option value="Feedback" id="cat3">Feedback</option> <!-- Shows Option 2 Row -->
                    <option value="Complains">Complains</option> <!-- Shows Option 3 Row -->
                    <option value="Requests">New Requests</option> <!-- Shows Option 4 Row -->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Header from contactSelect-->
            <th colspan="2" id="myHeader" name="myHeader" value="text">text</th>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Option 1 -->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Option 2 -->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Option 3 -->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Option 4 -->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- This is a temp row to be deleted -->
                <td>Selected Value:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="test" id="test" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

As for the jQuery, I can't figure it out expect for change the text of the row below the dropbox menu.

```
    <script>
        function changeVal() {
            document.getElementById('myHeader').html=document.getElementById('contactSelect').value;
            $('#myHeader').text(document.getElementById('contactSelect').value);
            alert(document.getElementById('myHeader').text);
            alert(document.getElementById('contactSelect').value);
        }
    </script>
```

How can I show/hide the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error as you can't apply a jQuery method on a dom node at this line:

```
document.getElementById('myHeader').html=document.getElementById('contactSelect').value;
 //------------this cause in error---^^^^
```

You can change markup a bit like adding select values as a class/ID to the respective trs:

```js
function changeVal() {

  if (this.value != 'default') {
    $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('.row').hide();
    $('.' + this.value).show();
  } else {
    $('.row').show();
  }
  $('#myHeader').html(this.value).toggle(this.value != 'default'); // use here to hidenshow
}

  $('#contactSelect').change(changeVal).trigger('change'); // <---and you need to trigger it on page load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Contact Details</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company Name:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company Representative Name:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company Representative Email:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company Representative Mobile Number:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Contact Type:
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="contactSelect" id="contactSelect">
        <!-- Function showHide Show work on table elements -->
        <option value="default" selected>Pelease select ...</option>
        <!-- Hide all 4 rows below -->
        <option value="General" id="cat2">General Inquiry</option>
        <!-- Shows Option 1 Row -->
        <option value="Feedback" id="cat3">Feedback</option>
        <!-- Shows Option 2 Row -->
        <option value="Complains">Complains</option>
        <!-- Shows Option 3 Row -->
        <option value="Requests">New Requests</option>
        <!-- Shows Option 4 Row -->
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Header from contactSelect-->
    <th colspan="2" id="myHeader" name="myHeader" value="text">text</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Option 1 -->
    <td></td>
    <tr class='row General'>
      <!-- Option 1 -->
      <td>General</td>
      <td>General</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row Feedback'>
      <!-- Option 2 -->
      <td>Feedback</td>
      <td>Feedback</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row Complains'>
      <!-- Option 3 -->
      <td>Complains</td>
      <td>Complains</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row Requests'>
      <!-- Option 4 -->
      <td>Requests</td>
      <td>Requests</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Selected Value:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="test" id="test" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is working fine .. But, for `<th colspan="2" id="myHeader" name="myHeader" value="text">text</th>` .. I want it to be hidden with `default` option, but to be visible with all other

Comment: @sikas updated and one thing to notice you have to remove the inline `onchange` handler.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need, depending on the drop down show the rows of that respective elements,

```js
$('#contactSelect').change(function() {
        $('.test').hide()
        document.getElementById('myHeader').html=document.getElementById('contactSelect').value;
        var value = document.getElementById('contactSelect').value
        $('#myHeader').text(document.getElementById('contactSelect').value);
        alert(document.getElementById('myHeader').text);
        alert(document.getElementById('contactSelect').value);
        $('#'+value).toggle()
   })
```

```css
<style>
.test { display: none;}
</style>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Contact Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Representative Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Representative Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Representative Mobile Number:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Contact Type:
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="contactSelect" id="contactSelect" onchange="changeVal();"> <!-- Function showHide Show work on table elements -->
                    <option value="default" selected>Pelease select ...</option> <!-- Hide all 4 rows below -->
                    <option value="General" id="cat2">General Inquiry</option> <!-- Shows Option 1 Row -->
                    <option value="Feedback" id="cat3">Feedback</option> <!-- Shows Option 2 Row -->
                    <option value="Complains">Complains</option> <!-- Shows Option 3 Row -->
                    <option value="Requests">New Requests</option> <!-- Shows Option 4 Row -->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Header from contactSelect-->
            <th colspan="2" id="myHeader" name="myHeader" value="text"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="test" id="General"> <!-- Option 1 -->
            <td>General Inquiry</td>
            <td>General Inquiry</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="test" id="Feedback"> <!-- Option 2 -->
            <td>Feedback</td>
            <td>Feedback</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="test" id="Complains"> <!-- Option 3 -->
            <td>Complains</td>
            <td>Complains</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="test" id="Requests"> <!-- Option 4 -->
            <td>New Requests</td>
            <td>New Requests</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- This is a temp row to be deleted -->
                <td>Selected Value:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="test" id="test" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Now once you select a value from drop down, its respective div wii be shown.

[Here is the working fiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/sravanaravind/zpto9ku9/)

Comment: Thanks! but what about the row that contains text by default? I need it to be hidden with the first option only

Comment: didn't get u? please say again in brief?

Comment: I updated the answer please check. If you find my answer useful, please accept it.

Comment: it did work, but also another answer helped more .. but your is great as well .. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function changeVal() {
  $('#contactSelect').change(function(){
    $('tr:eq(0)').hide(); //.show() to show again
    });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Contact Details</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company Name:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company Representative Name:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company Representative Email:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company Representative Mobile Number:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Contact Type:
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="contactSelect" id="contactSelect" onchange="changeVal();">
        <!-- Function showHide Show work on table elements -->
        <option value="default" selected>Pelease select ...</option>
        <!-- Hide all 4 rows below -->
        <option value="General" id="cat2">General Inquiry</option>
        <!-- Shows Option 1 Row -->
        <option value="Feedback" id="cat3">Feedback</option>
        <!-- Shows Option 2 Row -->
        <option value="Complains">Complains</option>
        <!-- Shows Option 3 Row -->
        <option value="Requests">New Requests</option>
        <!-- Shows Option 4 Row -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Header from contactSelect-->
    <th colspan="2" id="myHeader" name="myHeader" value="text">text</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Option 1 -->
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Option 2 -->
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Option 3 -->
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Option 4 -->
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- This is a temp row to be deleted -->
    <td>Selected Value:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="test" id="test" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show / hide an element. show() and hide() to just do it once. You should select by an id or name instead of the nth element like I do.

Answer (score 0):

TO change the "text" row

```js
$("#contactSelect").on('change', function(){
  $("#myHeader").text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Contact Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Representative Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Representative Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company Representative Mobile Number:</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Contact Type:
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="contactSelect" id="contactSelect" onchange="changeVal();"> <!-- Function showHide Show work on table elements -->
                    <option value="default" selected>Pelease select ...</option> <!-- Hide all 4 rows below -->
                    <option value="General" id="cat2">General Inquiry</option> <!-- Shows Option 1 Row -->
                    <option value="Feedback" id="cat3">Feedback</option> <!-- Shows Option 2 Row -->
                    <option value="Complains">Complains</option> <!-- Shows Option 3 Row -->
                    <option value="Requests">New Requests</option> <!-- Shows Option 4 Row -->
                  </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Header from contactSelect-->
            <th colspan="2" id="myHeader" name="myHeader" value="text">text</th>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Option 1 -->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Option 2 -->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Option 3 -->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Option 4 -->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- This is a temp row to be deleted -->
                <td>Selected Value:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="test" id="test" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
As for the jQuery, I can't figure it out expect for change the text of the row below the dropbox menu.
```